# How can I get Apache to treat users as other for file permissions

Tags: apache-http-server

The following is assuming Apache is running as www-data:www-data

I have a directory owned by www-data
Permissions are
U: rxw
G: rxw
O: ---

What I'd like to have happen is when, say a php script runs, it can write to that folder since it'd be running as www-data, but an external user trying to access anything in the directory would be treated as other, and unable to access.

Is that possible.  I could swear I've seen some web setups that function in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish what you want, the PHP script will need to run as a different user than the web server. The script user would be given permissions to read/write to a folder that www-data cannot access. Here's a question on Server Fault about [setting a PHP script to run as a different user](https://serverfault.com/questions/7589/how-do-you-run-a-php-script-as-the-files-owner-rather-than-as-the-webserver-us)

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but I've seen shared hosts where file perms can be set, and even HTML pages are inaccessible with a 700 permissions for example.  (as far as I know, PHP wasn't handing .html files)